# SSL Certificate error with Custom Domain in Openshift Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, vps, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a wordpress installation to Openshift but I can't refer my custom domain without a ssl certificate error when in the backend. I read a [article](http://blog.ochotnicky.com/2013/02/06/moving-my-blog-to-wordpress-on-openshift/) and it says that it is expected, but I coundn't find how to get it working properly. The CNAME and domain related issues with Openshift are OK. Is there a way to manage it or is it just a thing they aren't allowing non premium users have access to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time the free developer preview does not have the ability to use custom SSL on domain aliases.  However, that will be part of the paid plans as described on https://www.openshift.com/developers/pricing.  More updates to those plans coming very soon.

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom SSL certificate to your application, you will have to first upgrade to the "sliver plan". Then you can follow this tutorial (http://cloudhostingsource.com/setup-ssl-certificate-openshift) to add the certificate to your app.

Added 18 March 2014: OpenShift just announced the Bronze plan which will also allow you to have SNI based SSL without having to go all the way to the $20/month Silver plan.  If you keep to the 3 small gears, it can still be free.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add an SSL certificate to your domain (if you really need it) by upgrading to the Bronze plan or you can indicate to your Wordpress to use http instead for the admin content. To do so, change the following in your wp-config.php file:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); ---> define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

And you should be done, you will be able to access your admin content through http.